# CertificateTransparency: Failure: No certificates

Tags: android, certificate, client-certificates, certificate-transparency

Hello I implemented this library (https://github.com/babylonhealth/certificate-transparency-android) with okhttp/certificate pinning (using TrustKit)
the problem is that i received an error even tho the hostname has the logs
checking in [Google report](https://transparencyreport.google.com/https/certificates)
and there is a CT's log
im using the following config:

```kotlin
certificateTransparencyInterceptor {
        +"*.myhostname.io"
        failOnError = false
        logger = BasicAndroidCTLogger(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
    }
```

but I receive from logcat
CertificateTransparency: domain.myhostname.io Failure: No certificates
the okHttp is like this:

```kotlin
okHttpBuilder.addInterceptor(authInterceptor)
        .sslSocketFactory(OkHttp3Helper.getSSLSocketFactory(), OkHttp3Helper.getTrustManager())
        .addInterceptor(OkHttp3Helper.getPinningInterceptor())
        .addNetworkInterceptor(getCertificateTransparencyInterceptor())
        .sslSocketFactory(certificatePinning.getSSLSocketFactory(),
            certificatePinning.getTrustManager())
        .followRedirects(false)
        .followSslRedirects(false)
        .build()
```

im adding the intereptor in `.addNetworkInterceptor` 
the certificate is logged by `google_xenon2021`and `cloudflare_nimbus2021`  and they are in the default list
https://www.gstatic.com/ct/log_list/log_list.json

I'm trying to figure out what the problem is but I have no idea,

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the CT library (now hosted at https://github.com/appmattus/certificatetransparency/) only supports retrieving SCTs (Signed Certificate Timestamp) that are embedded in the certificate as an X.509v3 extension.

So if your domain is providing them through a TLS extension then the library will unfortunately not work.

You should be able to check by looking at your certificates details in your web browser and looking for an Embedded Signed Certificate Timestamp List entry:

[image: Embedded Signed Certificate Timestamp List]